# after tapping on notification app not launch in android 12 version?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-12

My app uses FCM for notifications. When the user taps the notification on Android 12, the application does not launch, whereas it does on lower versions.

The FirebaseMessagingService code is below.

```
private RemoteViews getCustomDesign(String title, String message) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_collapsed);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.collapsed_notification_title, title);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.collapsed_notification_info, message);
    return remoteViews;
}

@SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag")
public void showNotification(Context context, NotificationData data) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    String channel_id = "Default";
    intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, data.getNotificationId());
    intent.putExtra(LEAD_ID, data.getLeadId());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    }else {
        notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logoo)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(getCustomDesign(data.getTitle(), data.getMessage()));
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channel_id, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: did you test on emulator?

Comment: Try to test without setCustomContentView

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Yes, we did test on emulator as well as real device.

Comment: Were you able to figure the issue here @MaheshJadhav, because I am seeing the same issue with out app - in this case if the notification payload contains "notification" - the system tray is updated but the app is never launched. I tried to check whether there is any trampoline dependency and there was none

Comment: Did anyone found a solution? I am also facing this in Android 12 Samsung

Answer (score 4):

Please check your com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging version in build.gradle
After hours of searching I found out that the Firebase Team fixed it in v22.0.0
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v22-0-0